# Ajax (jquery) wp_query pagination returns -1

Tags: wp-query, jquery, pagination, ajax, previous-post-link

I am currently developing an ajaxified theme for wordpress. I am listing the posts in a particular category, but the pagination returns -1 when clicked. Lets say I set showposts to 3 and a particular category has 2 posts, the link to previous posts does not show up as expected. Now if the category has 5 posts, the link to previous posts shows up, again as expected, but when I click on it, -1 is returned. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$category = get_category_by_slug($_POST['catname']);
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query->query('cat='.$category->term_id.'&showposts=1&paged='.$paged);
?>
<script>
$('.pagi a').click(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       var link = $(this).attr('href');
       $('#b_contentwrapper').load(link);
});
</script>
<?php
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    get_the_title();
endwhile;
?>
<div class="pagi"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="pagi"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
<?php
?>
```

Also, the link of the previous post is `http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2` which I suspect might be the root of the problem.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is check for any plugins that affect search results. The reason is that I had the 'Search Everything' plugin running. While it was meant to search for more results and highlight the search terms, it will change any instance of `new WP_Query();` making it useless.

This is the callback function to load posts with ajax. The calling function works like any other client side request, echoing the results to an empty div.

```
function cbSearch()
{
    $counter = 1;
    $max = 4;
    $html = "";
    //Variables passed through $_POST
    $s = $_POST['src'];
    //the first time you call this function page number should be 1
    //Additional pages/functions/links are created with this code
    $page_num = $_POST['idx'];

    //Assuming the old $wp_query is basically null, 
    //there's no reason to copy previous parameters, just make a new one
    $search_query = array('s' => $s, 'posts_per_page' => $max, 'paged' => $page_num, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish');
    $search = new WP_Query($search_query);

    //use the object created, have_posts() alone will use global $wp_query
    if ($search->have_posts())
    {
            //The variables required to figure out next or previous page
            //Total number of post that match $s
        $total = $search->found_posts;
            //Post count for the page you're on
        $post_count = $search->post_count;
            //The maximum amount of pages to display all of the post results
        $page_count = ceil($search->max_num_pages);

        while ($search->have_posts())
        {
                    //Setup post data !important
            $search->the_post();

                    //Now your in the loop, use any loop functions you want
            $title = highlight(get_the_title(), $s);
        }
        $html = "<div id='news-page-nav'>";
            //Since we know what page we're on we know where to go
        $pre = $page_num - 1;
        $nex = $page_num + 1;
        if ($pre > 0)
        {
            $html .= "<span class='left fg-grey-light pointer' onclick='searchPosts(" . $pre . ");return false;' >P</span>";
        }
        if ($nex <= $page_count)
        {
            $html .= "<span class='right fg-grey-light pointer' onclick='searchPosts(" . $nex . ");return false;' >N</span>";
        }
        $html .= "</div>";
        echo $html;
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
    }
    die();
}
function highlight($str, $mts)
{
    $keys = explode(" ", $mts);
    $title = preg_replace('/(' . implode('|', $keys) . ')/iu', '<span class="bg-highlight">\0</span>', $str);
    return $title;
}
```

It is impossible to use previous/next posts link with ajax because the links provided are urls which would load a new page. I had to remind myself that, with AJAX, the page does not reload to serve up new content. Where you have previous/next posts link I've created two 'links' that call the ajax function again but with a different page number. Now you can page search results without using WP's default url parameters. Something to keep in mind is how this will affect search engine results.